# keypress on event type from a socket connection in python

Tags: python, sockets, client

first of all, i am totally new to programming. my last experience with programming was in school with turbo pascal, 15 years ago :) 
i have searched my code so far on the internet and get some ideas from a similar javascript.

i want a keypress if a specific event type comes from a socket connection. the code to connect to the server is already working, but i cant filter the types coming in from the socket.

thats my code for the connection:

```
# Imports #
import socketio

# Vars #
sio = socketio.Client()

# Your Socket API Token from streamlabs /settings/api-settings #
token = ''

# Connection #
sio.connect('https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=' + token)

# Code #
@sio.on("connect")
def on_connect():
    print("Connected to Streamlabs, Wait for Events")

@sio.on("event")
def on_message(data):
    print((data))

@sio.on("disconnect")
def on_disconnect():
    print("Disconnected.....")
```

now, if i simulate an follow event on the server, i get this output:

```
{'type': 'follow', 'message': [{'name': 'KayPure', 'isTest': True, '_id': 
'31a0f9db75b6f815c0e25cc6f14d015a'}], 'for': 'twitch_account', 'event_id': 
'evt_db9fc4f099a6bd83aa9779d43fccf4a9'}
```

or a subscription event:

```
{'type': 'subscription', 'message': [{'name': 'KayPure', 'isTest': True, 
'months': 1, 'message': 'This is a test', 'emotes': None, 'sub_plan': 
'1000', '_id': '725cb1e1cbdbb31d4122ccf266d4a7bf'}], 'for': 
'twitch_account', 'event_id': 'evt_6ad1f8d2f38e5410eaaed3cbf40843b5'}
```

i want to output only the type and the name of the events. i dont need the rest of the event information. then, i want to simulate e.g keypress "a" on follow, keypress "b" on subsription.

the background is: the keypress triggers a scene in a lightning software. this software runs on the same machine as the script, but it is not in the foreground.so thats another question. how to keypress in a specific window, which is in the background or minimized.

ive got an javascript similar to this one and this is already working. but the software has to be in the foreground. since i wanted to code more in python in the future, i whould love to get this running in python.

any ideas? I've tried a lot to output only the type of the event, but I dont know where to put the code in.

greetings from germany

k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, I understand you correctly. To restrict your output you need to get the relevant values for the keys `type` and `name` in your dictionary `data`:

```
@sio.on("event")
def on_message(data):
    print(data.get('type'), data.get('message')[0].get('name'))
```

`data` is a dictionary. With [`get`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) you access the value of the respective key. However, to get `name` you first need to get the value of `message` which is a list. The first and only element of the list is another dictionary. So, you access the first element `[0]` of the list and then again `get` the appropriate key's value of the dictionary.

To simulate a keypress you can use the [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module. Like this:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite('a')
```

This should get you going.

Comment: awesome, the data think work like a charm. thanks for the statement to data and dictionary. 

now, i have to route every event type to a specific keypress. there are 7 event types which has to press a different key.

like: 
`if type = follow 
pyautogui.typewrite('a')`